# Detailed view not showing from table view

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm a newbie to programing and I have a view based app that collects data from a SQLite database and show it in a table. That much I have got working however I can't get the app to show a detailed view once an item on the table is selected. Here is my code if anyone can help.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (dvController == nil)
        dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle: nil];

    Clubs *clubObj = [appDelegate.clubArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [clubObj hydrateDetailViewData];

    dvController.clubObj = clubObj;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

appDelegate = (ClubFindAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.title = @"Back";
```

}

Any help would be appreiciated.
Thanks

Comment: are you keeping an eye on the retain count of your clubObj?

Comment: Sorry what does that mean?@calvinBhai

Comment: @Wayne thelaws is right in viewBased template navigation controller is not there. You should start your app with navigationBased template which contains a navigation controller and tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you started with a view based app, perhaps your view controller doesn't have a `self.navigationController` instance available. Your view controller must be within a navigation controllers stack to push further view controllers.

To turn a view based app into one with a navigation controller all you really have to do is edit the app delegate as follows:

```
// view based app template code
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

becomes

```
UINavigationController * controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

You might also want to save the navigationController as a property of the application delegate also.

Comment: if you're not using the rootViewController way of setting the view like in my edit, replace the second line with: [self.window addSubview:controller.view];

Comment: I have added a naigation controller to the appDelegate as shown in my code below. How do I connect the detailed view to the controller `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]; [self.window addSubview:viewController.view]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES; }` I think that it is correct because don't I need the navigation controller to set up the table in the first place (which is working correcytly)@thelaws @Rahul Vyas

Comment: @Wayne please see my edited answer for how to create your viewController inside a navigationcontroller. In general, you shouldn't be adding two view controllers to your window.